# Check if the clicked dom element changes the current web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm trying to test if the clicked dom element changes the url, and I'm trying this on multiple web pages, i'm doing it by checking if the dom element is anchor tag

```
document.body.addEventListener('click',function(event){
domElement = $(event.target);
if(domElement.closest('a').length){
console.log('closest A');
}
}
```

But this doesn't work for all elements since some are anchors but page doesn't change, is there a way to check if it also changes the web page I'm currently working on ? Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like a bit of a non-starter - how will you check if there's some code that does `$("#btn").click(() => location.href = ...)` or `window.history.back();` or `<div onclick="location.href=...">` or any other of the myriad ways to change the page?  What about `window.history.pushState` which changes the url but doesn't load the page?   For [anchors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) that don't change the page, *one* format might be a url fragment like 'href="#id"`.  You'll also need to check for `target=` (not `_self`) as that may load in a different tab/window

Comment: @freedomn-m the thing is that I want to save the clicked element, which is I guess isn't possible through window.history.pushState or window.history.back(); So I thought the best way to do it is to check if the element is an anchor. But it's not too accurate the way I'm doing it. So I'm trying to know if it's possible to make it more accurate knowing that I want to save the clicked dom element.

Comment: Could you explain what the end goal is?   Sounds like you want to know which element was clicked, rather than which elements change the web page.   If you just record *every* element as it is is clicked, then the last one recorded would be the one that caused the page to change.

Comment: @freedomn-m I want to get to type of clicks and the dom element clicked either if it's an anchor tag then it's a link change else it's a simple click. But for anchors it doesn't work all the time since sometimes an anchor doesn't change the page.